# size of reference variable in c++

Tags: c++

I was wondering why this question wasn't discussed in stack overflow?
reference is just an other name to variable so how does execution happen at memory level

are references implemented as pointers inside?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking here. You seem to be asking four different questions.

Comment: @Robᵩ: If we ignore the first Q, which is neither constructive nor with definitive answer. Rest all 3 Q's can be answered in definitive manner. I don't think this needs to be closed.Voting to ReOpen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How references are implemented is purely an implementation detail. But Yes, most implementations would implement them using pointers.
`sizeof` operator applied on an reference gives you the size of the element it referes to.

> **What is the size of the reference itself?**

**C+11 Standard: § 8.3.2.4**

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (3.7).

Note that, **Unspecified** means that an compiler implementation does not need to document how it implements a reference. Neither should you consider the implementation to be anything specific. In short, the language standard treats reference implementation as an detail which user of the language does not need to know and hence it abstracts this detail.

Comment: The last one is true if you read it as asking about `sizeof(someReference)`. But I think he's asking how much space the reference itself takes under the hood, for a specific implementation.

Comment: @delnan: Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @delnan you are right.Thank u all for u r responses.In the compilation process how does the compiler treat the reference and generate instructions. At least some one could point out a web link :)

Comment: A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-ﬁelds all having
non-zero width. [ Note: Various features of the language, such as references and virtual functions, might
involve additional memory locations that are not accessible to programs but are managed by the implementation. — end note taken from c++ standard