# Do C++ references take any memory?

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size of reference variable in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964690/size-of-reference-variable-in-c)

Do C++ references consume any memory? If not, how can they be passed as arguments to functions?

Comment: Remember that references are just syntactical sugar for pointers, so yes they take up memory.

Comment: @TomKnapen, not quite. References are additional names for an object; they cannot be reassigned, not assigned, invalid or null in well-formed program. Sometimes they work like const pointers, but sometimes they are just syntactical sugar for the object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes they do and sometimes they don't. When they need to (such as when used as data members), they do.

For an example where they don't need to:

```
int a = 1;
int &b = a;
```

Now, the compiler can treat `b` purely as an alias for `a`. There is never a requirement to allocate memory for `b` here, because references aren't objects.

Another case that may be of interest:

```
int some_function_call(); // function returns by value
const int &c = some_function_call();
```

In this case `c` is a reference to the temporary object that is the return value of the call. The temporary's life is extended to the scope of `c`, so in that sense you could say that `c` consumes an int-sized piece of memory. But there's no particular reason that the compiler needs to allocate any more than that. You might see the same emitted code as if you'd written `const int c = some_function_call();`, which also creates an `int` object with identical lifetime and the same name `c`.

As for passing them as parameters -- it depends on the calling convention whether parameters occupy memory or not. Some parameters might get passed in registers. Then it depends on the callee code whether that register ends up getting spilled to stack somewhere during the execution of the function. But yes, when passed as parameters and the function call not inlined, reference parameters must occupy "something", because the caller must somehow let the callee know the address of the object referred to by the reference (the "referand").

All the same things can be said of pointers provided that you don't take the address of the pointer. But in the case of pointers it's an optimization on the compiler's own initiative. In the case of references they're explicitly defined in the standard to be aliases, and pointers (or at any rate addresses) happen to be the obvious means to implement that in cases where the compiler can't treat a reference purely as an entry in its compile-time name lookup table. The only essential difference is what happens in the abstract machine described by the standard -- after implementation and optimization it may well amount to the same thing.

Comment: @Hooch: No You are wrong.Please check standard specification quote in marked duplicate.

Comment: @Hooch :)) pointers don't always take up memory.

Comment: @Hooch §8.3.2/4: "It is unspeciﬁed whether or not a reference
requires storage."

Comment: @slomojo: "they usually know what they're talking about". Steady on, I wouldn't go that far ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop well, I know you're a dummy, but I mean them other ones ;)

Comment: @JamesKanze +1 for QTFM.